# Specifying grid column/row size in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to create a grid with tailwind css where the first column is very narrow and the second one is very wide. Normally I find the tailwind docs very intuitive but I'm not understanding this one. Using `grid-cols-{n}` I can create equally sized columns but I don't understand how to make differently sized columns. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example of a 2 column grid where the first column is narrow, and the second one is not:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[max-content_1fr] gap-x-4">
  <div class="bg-red-200 p-4">Column 1</div>
  <div class="bg-green-200 p-4">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/FTLi83L5zI

I'll assume that's not what you want as it's not 100% clear from your question. So here's a different example using a 12 column grid, you can span multiple columns to achieve something along the lines of what you are asking for:

```html
  <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-4 text-center">
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4 col-span-2">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4 col-span-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
    <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4">Col</div>
  </div>
```

Tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XtUOu2cDD9

Finally, you could also do this:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-4 text-center">
  <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4 col-span-4">Col</div>
  <div class="bg-slate-400 p-4 col-span-8">Col</div>
</div>
```

Tailwind play: https://play.tailwindcss.com/bAnPhCdNfc

Further examples: [arbitrary values with Tailwind](https://morganfeeney.com/guides/advanced-responsive-grids-with-tailwind)

Comment: I ended up using a similar solution as you proposed in your first example using a slightly different syntax `grid grid-cols-[2rem,8fr]`

Answer (score 4):

If you want create columns with different widths then it will be an implicitly-created grid.

```html
<div class="p-5 bg-slate-200">
  <div class="grid grid-flow-col auto-cols-max gap-x-5">
    <div class="bg-white w-20">Hello 1</div>
    <div class="bg-white w-40">Hello 2</div>
    <div class="bg-white">Hello 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7XjBZDzwml

This is the relevant documentation here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-columns

And it explains how you can customize your theme if needed too.

Comment: Your link just shows a single row, which is not a grid. I do want to create a responsive grid where my child divs have a specified width, and I want the grid to wrap and create as many rows as necessary.

Comment: I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77181779/is-it-possible-to-use-tailwind-to-create-a-responsive-grid-dynamic-number-of-co

Answer (score 2):

In the end the way I did it was:

```
grid grid-cols-[2rem,8fr]
```

Which creates a grid with 2 columns one, the first one 2rems wide the second one being 8fr wide

Comment: That's almost identical to the first example in my answer: `grid-cols-[max-content_1fr]`

Comment: is the syntax where you use an underline an alternative to using a comma?

Comment: Correct, in the end the example I shared compiles to: `grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;`, you can validate this yourself using Tailwind Play

Comment: Ah okay, that's what was tripping me up - I will mark yours as the answer then